# How to filter by Edm.DateTimeOffset in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When testing the following three filter query strings in the Azure Search index search explorer, they all return the same count. It looks like it is not filtering the dates at all.

What is the correct way to filter fields that are the `Edm.DateTimeOffset` type?

**Three query strings tested**

```
date_time_field eq 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z&$count=true
date_time_field lt 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z&$count=true
date_time_field ge 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z&$count=true
```

**Sample 'date_time_field' dates in the search index**

```
2019-12-30T00:00:00Z
2020-01-08T11:01:13Z
2020-01-09T00:00:00Z
2019-12-30T00:00:00Z
2019-12-17T13:39:02Z
```

Comment: Is that the entire query string? It’s missing $filter=

Answer (score 2):

The query string was missing `$filter=`.

Full and working query

```
$filter=date_time_field eq 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z&$count=true
```

Comment: How do we do the same in POST. When I add the json as `{"filter":"date_time_field eq 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"}`,  below, it gives the error: `{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. Unexpected end of input was found in JSON content. Not all object and array scopes were closed.\r\n"
    }
}`      Looks like other types work fine, DateTimeOffset seems to be causing the issue. Any idea?